# Gradle 3.4.x cannot apply plugin in project-specific behaviour

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am following documentation on multi-project builds
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

I have an external dependency that I am incorporating into my main build.gradle
Howere, getting an error

```
Error:Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.
```

A portion of my main build.gradle

```
project(':myexternallibrary') {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$versions.androidPluginVersion"
            // classpath "me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.0"
        }
    }



    android {
    }


    model {
        components {
            main() {
                sources {
                    java {
                        source {
                            srcDirs "src/main"
                        }
                        // configure the "java" source set
                    }
                }
            }
        }
  }
  **apply plugin: 'com.android.library'**
  dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        //    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  (I cannot apply com.android.library in the build.gradle of the myexternallibrary  (because I am using this library in Non-android builds as well)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.  There were several tricks to get the above to work (again the goal was to use the same Java library in Android and non android builds with AndroidStudio and IntelliJ community edition).

within build.gradle of the main app
I had to replace

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

with

```
apply plugin: com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin
```

I have no explanation, why I had to replace the plugin name with its class name.
This is probably a bug, and I found a post somewhere in 2013 referencing different, but similar question. So it seems that gradle did not fix it in last 4 years.

Here is how the updated section looks
...

```
project(':myexternallibrary') {
apply plugin: com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
}

//'com.android.tools.build
//apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
//apparently within a project we must specify a class name of the plugin
//without quotes...
apply plugin: com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin

model {
    components {
        main() {
            sources {
                java {
                    source {
                        srcDirs "src/main"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
}
```

}

Another thing I learned is that one has to keep build.gradle of the myexternallibrary  as 'dumb' as possible.  For example I had in there a directive to deposit temp build files into a different directory (because on windows the path length was exceeded)

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        buildDir = "${System.getenv('HOME')}/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
}
```

but that directive (buildDir), even though was working fine before, in this new build structure -- was causing gradle to confuse directories.. And I was getting a 'cannot find AndroidManifest.xml'...